# "cannot create directory `JAVA': Permission denied " how to solve this issue?

Tags: permissions, java

can anybody help me in solving this issue. I am new to Linux and here's 
problem:

```
gourab@gourab-RV509:/usr/share/java$ cd /
gourab@gourab-RV509:/$ cd usr
gourab@gourab-RV509:/usr$ mkdir JAVA
mkdir: cannot create directory `JAVA': Permission denied
gourab@gourab-RV509:/usr$
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `mkdir JAVA` use `sudo mkdir JAVA`, then enter your password.

That should fix it.

However, you only really need to use one command instead of these two or three.

```
cd / 
cd usr 
sudo mkdir JAVA
```

cd just changes the directory, no point in doing that. You can simply put the path of the file after mkdir, like so.

```
sudo mkdir /usr/JAVA
```

Comment: @grv.giit You can also use `sudo -i` to elevate to root, then do all future commands(until you close the terminal) without the sudo.

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ: thanks got it this will solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

`Permission denied` means you have to be a `superuser or root` to create files/folder on a specific directory. So to create folder that needs a root permission, you need to simply add `sudo` before your command: `sudo mkdir -p JAVA`

Comment: worked perfectly for me . Thanks for support !! :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a directory in any folder other than `/home/username`, where `username` is your account's `username`, you need to prepend `mkdir` with `sudo`, so create the folder like this:
 `sudo mkdir JAVA`